# jquery store json object from url in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I use the .getJSON() function to save a json object as a javascript variable?

```
var js = 
$.getJSON(url, 
    function(data) {...}
);
```

do I need the `function(data) {...}` callback?

The var would look like normal json format (like a dictionary in python?)

```
{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2014-07-18", ...
```

Comment: The `function(data){...}` part is the callback of getJSON, `data` is the JSON response that you will get.

Comment: You mean you want to receive data returned by `$.getJSON` in a `JavaScript` variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to declare the variable first and then assign the value in the success function as such:

```
var js;
$.getJSON(url, 
    function(data) {
        js = data;
        // or use your data here by calling yourFunction(data);
    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

If your code looks something like the following, then it probably won't work:

```
var js;
$.getJSON(url, 
    function(data) {
        js = data;
        // or use your data here by calling yourFunction(data);
    }
);
$("div").html(js);
```

That's because the `$.getJSON()` is an asynchronous function. That means the code underneath will continue executing without waiting for the $.getJSON to finish. Instead you would want to use the variable inside the success function as such:

```
var js;
$.getJSON(url, 
    function(data) {
        // the code inside this function will be run,
        // when the $.getJSON finishes retrieving the data
        js = data;
        $("div").html(js);
    }
);
```

Comment: $("div").html(js);  doesnt print to my html div though?

Comment: Thanks. That is still not showing anything in the div though. I want to actually print out the json object on in my div.

Comment: before `$("div").html(js);` have you tried adding `console.log(js);` to make sure the `$.getJSON` is retrieving the data correctly? If not, let me know what it prints

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to receive `data` returned by `$.getJSON` in a javascript variable.

```
var js;

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    js = data;
    // you can even pass data as parameter to your target function like myFunct(data);
});
```